# Fixing font size in tex2image graphics

Tags: r, r-exams

I created several graphics with different font sizes using the `tex2image()` function from the `exams` package. But the parameter `pt`, which should specify the font size, only seems to have an effect on the line spacing. I want to fix the font so that it appears the same size in all images.

For illustration try creating the following image with `pt = 12` vs. `pt = 5`. The output is shown below.

```
library('exams')

tex <- 'test\\\\test\\\\test'

tex2image(tex, format = "png", dir= ".", name = 'test-12', resize = 350, pt = 12)
```

| `pt = 12` | `pt = 5` |
| --- | --- |
| [image: 12pt image] | [image: 5pt image] |

Comment: Could you please post a minimal, self-contained, reproducible example that clearly shows what the problem is? In principle, the font size via `pt` should have an effect but the actual size in the image also depends on the size of the PNG image and how this is included in the HTML or PDF document afterwards. So it is hard to say what exactly the problem is without a clear and concise example.

Comment: I added an example @AchimZeileis, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this behavior is that the default is to resize PNG output from `tex2image()` to a certain number of pixels: `resize = 650`. Thus, in your `pt = 5` setup a smaller PDF and PNG is generated first compared to the `pt = 12` setup but both are scaled to 650 pixels afterwards. This makes the resulting text similarly large but the `pt = 5` version more pixelated.

The first way to avoid this would be to set `resize = NULL` so that no rescaling is done. Then you would need to make sure to include the resulting PNG images "as is" without any rescaling in HTML.

Alternatively, you can set a certain `width = ...` (in inches, > 1) for the text box to make sure that all images have the same width, thus preserving relative font sizes. This approach is illustrated by:

```
tex2image("Short text",                                  width = 2, pt = 12, dir = ".", name = "tex2image-short")
tex2image("A considerably longer text",                  width = 2, pt = 12, dir = ".", name = "tex2image-long-12")
tex2image("A considerably longer text with small fonts", width = 2, pt =  5, dir = ".", name = "tex2image-long-5")
```

[image: Short text, large font]

[image: Long text, large font]

[image: Long text, small font]